# JAVA: trying to output a set of customers but only printing first customer

Tags: java

I am inputting customer details and saving them into a file. When I print them out, only the first customer is being printed. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


          Customer e = new Customer();
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("");
          e.setCustID(scan.nextLong());
          e.setName(scan.next());
          e.setSurname(scan.next());

          try {
              FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("customer.txt"),true);
              ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
              out.writeObject(e);
              out.close();
              fileOut.close();
              System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in /tmp/employee.ser\n\n");
          }catch(IOException i) {
             i.printStackTrace();
          }


          try {
              FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("customer.txt");
              ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
              e = (Customer) in.readObject();
              in.close();
              fileIn.close();
           }catch(IOException i) {
              i.printStackTrace();
              return;
           }catch(ClassNotFoundException c) {
              System.out.println("Customer class not found");
              c.printStackTrace();
              return;

           }

          File file = new File("customer.txt");
          if(file.exists()) {


                StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                FileInputStream fileReader = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileReader, "UTF-8"));

                String line =  buffReader.readLine();

                while(line != null) {

                    System.out.print(e.getCustID()+"\t");
                    System.out.print(e.getName()+"\t");
                    System.out.print(e.getSurname()+"\n");
                    line=buffReader.readLine();

                }




                //if line is null, we have reached EOF (end of file)
                buffReader.close();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("File not found!");
            }


          System.out.println("Deserialized Employee...");
          System.out.println("Name: " + e.getCustID());
          System.out.println("Address: " + e.getName());
          System.out.println("SSN: " + e.getSurname());

          //  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm
          // to try http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/writing-the-file.php
       }





}
```

Comment: with "while((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null)"  is only reading the first entries in each line of the text file. but in each line there are multiple entries and the inputs are serialized

Comment: is the data correctly written to the file.completely?

Comment: Sample of data in file: ¬í sr Customer÷w¬;RZ+ L Namet Ljava/lang/String;L Surnameq ~

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you have is that you can't append objects to an ObjectOutputStream after it has been closed (i.e. after running the program once). Therefore you need to enter all your Customer data during the initial program run. If you need to run program multiple times then you need to look for other solutions as to how to write previous data to new ObjectOutputStream, etc.

If you are happy to enter all Customer data in one program run then the following simplified code example should work:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("customer.txt"));
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut));

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {

            boolean writing = true;
            while (writing) {
                Customer e = new Customer();

                System.out.println("Enter Customer Details:");
                e.setCustID(scan.nextLong());
                e.setName(scan.next());
                e.setSurname(scan.next());
                out.writeObject(e);
                System.out.println("Enter More Details ? [Y|N]:");
                writing = scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y") ? true : false;
            }
        } catch (Exception i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            scan.close();
        }

        File file = new File("customer.txt");
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(fileIn));

        while (true) {

            Customer c;
            try {
                c = (Customer) in.readObject();
                System.out.print(c.getCustID() + "\t");
                System.out.print(c.getName() + "\t");
                System.out.print(c.getSurname() + "\n");
            } catch (EOFException e1) {
                break;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        in.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What I need to do is that the data which I enter whenever I run the program.  previous inouts must be available in the text file. Moreover, I need to look for a customer through a unique ID: that is custID in this case. WHat would be appropriate to use for the latter scenario?

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Comment: @mariusmifsud, each time you run the prog you need to read any existing data saved in the file and write it to a new `ObjectOutputStream` before entering any new `Customer` details saving the stream and so on (not very efficient but should do). For the second part, a simple way would be to loop through all Customers picking out the ones with matching custID (if custID is supposed to be unique then you can break out after a match is found).